# Extract data along with html tag when data is given as search item

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to extract html data. I need to extract the html tags along with the data if data is given as search item provided the tag can be anything.

As a sample considering the following html code

```
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Python Program</h1>
 
   <span class = true>Geeks</span>
   <span class = false>Geeks New</span>
 
   <li class = 1 >Python Program</li>
   <li class = 2 >Python Code</li>
   <li class = 3 >Hello</li>
 
   <table>
       <tr>Website</tr>
   </table>
```

Using the following code if tag is known, then the entire tag with data is available

```
pattern = 'Hello'
text1 = soup.find_all('li', text = pattern)
print(text1)
```

This will give the

```
[<li class = 3 >Hello</li>]
```

But if I give 'Hello' as search item I need to get all the tags which contain 'Hello' like

```
[<h1>Hello</h1>, <li class = 3 >Hello</li>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `css selector` that checks if an element contains a string:

```
soup.select(':-soup-contains("Hello")')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ='''
<h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Python Program</h1>
 
   <span class = true>Geeks</span>
   <span class = false>Geeks New</span>
 
   <li class = 1 >Python Program</li>
   <li class = 2 >Python Code</li>
   <li class = 3 >Hello</li>
 
   <table>
       <tr>Website</tr>
   </table>
'''

pattern = 'Hello'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.select(f':-soup-contains({pattern})')
```

##### Output

```
[<h1>Hello</h1>, <li class="3">Hello</li>]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean instead of li tag

```
html = '''
  <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Python Program</h1>
 
   <span class = true>Geeks</span>
   <span class = false>Geeks New</span>
 
   <li class = 1 >Python Program</li>
   <li class = 2 >Python Code</li>
   <li class = 3 >Hello</li>
 
   <table>
       <tr>Website</tr>
   </table>
'''
pattern = 'Hello'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

text1 = soup.find_all(True, text = pattern)
print(text1)
```

**Output:**

```
[<h1>Hello</h1>, <li class="3">Hello</li>]
```